# What is a permutation-valued random variable

Tags: random-variables

I am reading in wikipedia about random permutation and here appear the next term "permutation-valued random variable". Could you give me a book where exist this definition please? Do you have any example?

Comment: In all likelihood random permutation and permutation valued random variable are the same thing.

Comment: Random variables are just measurable functions on probability spaces, so a permutation valued random variable is just a measurable map from a probability space to the set of permutations. Likely the sigma algebra on the permutations is the discrete one.

Comment: @cdipaolo Do you know  an example of probability space for a permutation-valued random variable?

Comment: @juaninf you could use $X=\{1,2,\ldots , n!\}$ with normalized counting measure, and then a bijection from $X$ to the set of permutations on $n$ elements would give you a uniform distribution on the permutations (a permutation valued random variable!)